# How to write a JUnit test for an atm validation program?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I'm new to java and I'm writing an ATM program where **user can enter pin code three times and if they fail to enter the correct one, their card is blocked.** I've tried to write a Junit test for the following code but I couldn't seem to figure it out. I have two classes AtmPin and AtmTester. AtmTester is where the main class is.

**AtmPin.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AtmPin {

   public static boolean validPIN(int user, int orignal){

      

       return user==orignal;

   }

   public static int getPin(Scanner sc){

      

       System.out.print("Enter PIN: ");

       int pin = sc.nextInt();

       return pin;

   }

  
}
```

**AtmTester.java**

```
package atm;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ATMTester {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

          

           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

           int i = 0, userpin;

          int PIN = 1234;
          while(i< 3){

              

               userpin = AtmPin.getPin(keyboard);

              

               if(AtmPin.validPIN(userpin, PIN)){

                   System.out.println("Your PIN is correct");

                   System.exit(0);

               }
               else {
                   System.out.println("Your PIN is incorrect");
               }
              

               i++;

           }

          

           System.out.println("Your Bank Card is blocked");

       }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try to search the internet for "kata":

A "kata", or "coding kata", is defined as an exercise in programming which helps hone your skills through practice and repetition.

Searching for "kata atm" found this:

- https://githubhelp.com/xpepper/ATM-kata-java

which may be a good starting point.

Each requerement of the kata can be translated to one or more junittests